# Graph Traversal But with restrictions based on edge properties

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am trying to traverse a graph but with some restrictions on which edges I can traverse. I am provided some data that relates to sports matches. The data is modelled like a hypergraph and I want to traverse subgraphs to pull out certain parts. For example take the data below.

```json
[
    {
      "interaction": {
        "interactionId": 5,
        "type": "pass"
      }
    },
    {
      "activity": {
        "activityId": 3,
        "sport": "football",
        "start_time": "2022-08-01"
      }
    },
    {
      "player": {
        "playerId": 2,
        "Name": "John"
      }
    },
    {
      "player": {
        "playerId": 1,
        "Name": "Dave"
      }
    },
    {
      "activityEdge": {
        "activityEdgeId": 56,
        "players": [
          1,
          2
        ],
        "activity": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "interactionEdge": {
        "interactionEdgeId": 782,
        "activityId": 56
      }
    },
    {
      "sourceInteractionEdge": {
        "sourceInteractionEdgeId": 123,
        "playerId": 1,
        "interactionId": 5,
        "activityId": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "sport": {
        "name": "football",
        "sportId": 89
      }
    },
    {
      "sportEdge": {
        "sportEdgeId": 78,
        "activityId": 3,
        "sportId": 89
      }
    },
    {
        "sportEdge": {
          "sportEdgeId": 78,
          "activityId": 4,
          "sportId": 89
        }
    },
    {
        "activity": {
            "activityId": 4,
            "sport": "football",
            "start_time": "2022-08-01"
        }
    },
    {
      "player": {
        "playerId": 90,
        "Name": "Bill"
      }
    },
    {
      "player": {
        "playerId": 91,
        "Name": "Bucket"
      }
    },
    {
      "activityEdge": {
        "activityEdgeId": 92,
        "players": [
          91,
          90
        ],
        "activity": 4
      }
    }
  ]
```

This can be loaded into python using networkx like this

```py
import networkx as nx
import json
from itertools import combinations
with open("data.json") as input_file:
    data = json.load(input_file)
G = nx.Graph()
for item in data:
    key = list(item.keys())[0]
    item_data = item.get(key)
    if "Edge" not in key:
        item_id = item_data.get(f"{key}Id")
        G.add_node(item_id)
    else:
        values = list()
        keys_of_interest = list()
        for nested_key in item_data:
            print(f"Top Level Key: {key}")
            print(f"Nested Key: {nested_key}")
            if nested_key != f"{key}Id":
                value = item_data.get(nested_key)
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    values.extend(value)
                else:
                    values.append(value)
        print(values)
        pairs = combinations(values, 2)
        print(list(pairs))
        G.add_edges_from(combinations(values, 2))
```

Apologies for the terrible code, it was a quick mock up. This produces a graph like so
[Example NetworkX Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF5Mi.png)

What I am trying to do is iterate over the activity pieces to create a list of activities and their associated information i.e player, interactions etc. The only issue is one activity can be linked to other activities via the "sport" property. Therefore running DFS or BFS will give me everything instead of the subgraph. For example

```py
for edge in nx.dfs_edges(G):
    print(edge)
#     (5, 1)
#     (1, 2)
#     (2, 3)
#     (3, 89)
#     (89, 4)
#     (4, 91)
#     (91, 90)
```

I am looking to only get [(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 3), (5, 3), (3, 89)] so don't traverse if it's a sports node for example.
What is the best way to approach this? Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Check the edge property BEFORE you add it. Do not add edges that should not be traversed.  If an edge is not in the graph, it cannot be traversed.

Comment: But I still need the edge to be there because otherwise I wouldn't be able to link an "activity" node to a "sport" node.

Comment: A link allows traversal from one node to another.  If you do not want to do the traversal then you do not need the link.

Comment: I don't think I've explained the problem well sorry. I need the link otherwise I cannot enrich the activity but I do not want to traverse the edge after that vertex and vice versa for the other activity

Comment: "I do not want to traverse the edge after that vertex"  So do not add the edges you do not want to traverse.

Comment: Hopefully my answer below helps to explain why I don't want to remove that edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to AveragePythonEnjoyer for the idea of this. I added the node type and then when I do a dfs, I don't add it to the stack if it's a node type I don't want to traverse any further ie

```py
def dfs_special(G, source=None, depth_limit=None, skip_nodes=["sportId"]):
    if source is None:
        # edges for all components
        nodes = G
    else:
        # edges for components with source
        nodes = [source]
    visited = set()
    if depth_limit is None:
        depth_limit = len(G)
    for start in nodes:
        if start in visited:
            continue
        visited.add(start)
        stack = [(start, depth_limit, iter(G[start]))]
        while stack:
            parent, depth_now, children = stack[-1]
            try:
                child = next(children)
                if child not in visited:
                    child_key = G.nodes[child].get("node_key")
                    if child_key in skip_nodes:
                        yield parent, child
                    else:
                        yield parent, child
                        visited.add(child)
                        if depth_now > 1:
                            stack.append((child, depth_now - 1, iter(G[child])))
            except StopIteration:
                stack.pop()
```

Then I call

```py
edges = list(dfs_special(G, source=3))
```

which gives me the edges I want to look at [(3, 1), (1, 2), (1, 5), (3, 89)].
This does still miss out (5, 3) as 5 would have already been a visited node but that's okay as I've still got all the data for this subgraph.

For example I can then iterate over the edges (ignore the terrible processing it was quick)

```py
    uniq_keys = list()
    all_data = list()
    for source, dest in edges:
        source_node = G.nodes[source]
        dest_node = G.nodes[dest]
        source_key = source_node.get("node_key")
        dest_key = dest_node.get("node_key")
        if source_node.get("data").get(source_key) not in uniq_keys:
            all_data.append(source_node.get("data"))
            uniq_keys.append(source_node.get("data").get(source_key))
        if dest_node.get("data").get(dest_key) not in uniq_keys:
            all_data.append(dest_node.get("data"))
            uniq_keys.append(dest_node.get("data").get(dest_key))
```

To output the relevant information about an event

```json
[
    {'activityId': 3, 'sport': 'football', 'start_time': '2022-08-01'},
    {'playerId': 1, 'Name': 'Dave'},
    {'playerId': 2, 'Name': 'John'},
    {'interactionId': 5, 'type': 'pass'},
    {'name': 'football', 'sportId': 89}
]
```

Comment: " I don't add it to the stack if it's a node type I don't want to traverse"  However your questions says: "some restrictions on which edges I can traverse"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem as well, while the comments are valid, i.e. not adding the edges in the first place, sometimes this is not possible or not desirable. My go to solution in your case would be:

In the creation of the graph I would add an attribute which reflects the node type. Then after creating the graph, I would delete the nodes based on the attribute value.

Example:

```
import networkx as nx
import json
from itertools import combinations


with open("data.json") as input_file:
    data = json.load(input_file)
    
    
G = nx.Graph()
for item in data:
    key = list(item.keys())[0]
    item_data = item.get(key)
    if "Edge" not in key:
        item_id = item_data.get(f"{key}Id")
        
        #add node type as an attribute and assign it the key value of your dict
        G.add_node(item_id, node_type = key)
        
    else:
        values = list()
        keys_of_interest = list()
        for nested_key in item_data:
            if nested_key != f"{key}Id":
                value = item_data.get(nested_key)
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    values.extend(value)
                else:
                    values.append(value)

        pairs = combinations(values, 2)
        G.add_edges_from(combinations(values, 2))

        
#filter out all the nodes with 'node_type' == 'activity'
nodes_to_remove = [n for n, d in G.nodes(data=True) if d['node_type'] == 'activity']

#>>>print(nodes_to_remove)
#[3, 4]

G.remove_nodes_from(nodes_to_remove)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - This comment actually helped me work out a good way to go about this. Only issue with this is I don't want to remove those nodes because I want to retain the information in them and use them to create one big event but I've used the concept of a node_key to help filter out nodes I want to stop traversing.

Comment: Why not just copy the graph keep it in memory and reuse it later?